# How to get the first Sunday of next month for a given date?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am looking for some logic to get the date get the first Sunday of next month for a given date using c#.
How to get the first Sunday of next month for a given date using c#?

Comment: There are various things you need to do for this. I'd start off by getting a DateTime for the first day of the next month. Then work out its day of the week (with the DayOfWeek property). Then based on those two pieces of information, you can work out the first Sunday of the month.

Comment: You are probably lucky that Jon Skeet has commented on your question :P

Comment: Where is your code ?

Answer (score 5):

You didn't show *any* effort but let's we code what [Jon says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026356/how-to-get-the-first-sunday-of-next-month-for-a-given-date#comment46294804_29026356) step by step;

> How to get the first Sunday of next month for a given date

We call `dt` as a [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) for a *given date* in your question. All months starts with `1` as a day number. That's why we can create a `DateTime` called `firstDayOfNextMonth`

```
DateTime firstDayOfNextMonth = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month + 1, 1);
```

Now what? Sure we need to check the day name and it is Sunday or not. Until when? Until we found a day as Sunday. That's why we need to iterate this day (*1 day per*) until we found it. We can use [`DayOfWeek` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that which gives as it's day name.

Let's define a `DateTime` as `firstSundayOfNextMonth` in our code;

```
DateTime firstSundayOfNextMonth;
```

And now iterate your first day of next week until we found a Sunday;

```
while (firstDayOfNextMonth.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
    firstDayOfNextMonth = firstDayOfNextMonth.AddDays(1);
}
```

When this `while` statement stop working? Yes, when we found the first Sunday. That's why we need to assign this value to `firstSundayOfNextMonth` variable outside of this loop.

```
while (firstDayOfNextMonth.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
    firstDayOfNextMonth = firstDayOfNextMonth.AddDays(1);
}

firstSundayOfNextMonth = firstDayOfNextMonth;
```

And we found it. `firstSundayOfNextMonth` is the first Sunday of the next month for a given `DateTime` (which is `dt` in our case).

Comment: Greatly explained! Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: It works fine but there is an issue if the month is December. It should be like this:
(today.Month + 1)%12

Answer (score 2):

```
public static DateTime GetFirstSundayOfNextMonth(DateTime givenDate)
{
    DateTime firstDayNextMonth = givenDate.AddDays(-givenDate.Day + 1).AddMonths(1);
    int diff = 7 - (int)firstDayNextMonth.DayOfWeek;
    return firstDayNextMonth.AddDays(diff);
}
```

Comment: Hiya there, while this may well answer the question, please be aware that other users might not be as knowledgeable as you. Why don't you add a little explanation as to why this code works? Thanks!

Comment: Well, today is the 05/04/2016 --> you're doing today - the number of the day --> last day of the previous month --> +1 first day of this month --> +1 month --> first day of the following month. Then you calculate which day of the week is the first and how many days you need to get to Sunday, and then you add those days.

Comment: If next month will start with `Sunday` then your code will return `2nd Sunday`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2015, 03, 13);
 DateTime dm = dt1.AddMonths(1);
 DateTime addm = new DateTime(dm.Year,dm.Month,1);
 var nextSunday = addm.AddDays(7 - (int)addm.DayOfWeek);
```

> You can put any date in place of `2015, 03, 13` like `year,month,day`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the next week day after a certain date, I found a simple way.

```
public static DateTime FirstDayOfWeekOnOrAfter(this DateTime date, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
  return date.AddDays(Math.Abs(dayOfWeek - date.DayOfWeek));
}

public static DateTime FirstDayOfWeekOnOrBefore(this DateTime date, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
  return date.AddDays(-Math.Abs(dayOfWeek - date.DayOfWeek));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime nextMonthfirstSunday;
        DayOfWeek firstDay = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month+1, 1).DayOfWeek;
        switch (firstDay)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                nextMonthfirstSunday = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month+1, 1);
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                nextMonthfirstSunday = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month + 1, 7);
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                nextMonthfirstSunday = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month + 1, 6);
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                nextMonthfirstSunday = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month + 1, 5);
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                nextMonthfirstSunday = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month + 1, 4);
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                nextMonthfirstSunday = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month + 1, 3);
                break;
            default://Saturday
                nextMonthfirstSunday = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month + 1, 2);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: In case of `DateTime.Now.Month` is `December` it will throw `exception`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static DateTime GetFirstSundayOfNextMonth(DateTime dt)
{
    dt = dt.AddMonths(1); // In case of December using new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month + 1, 1) could throw and error. So first use .AddMonths(1).
    dt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1); // Get first date of month
    return dt.AddDays((7 - dt.DayOfWeek.GetHashCode() + DayOfWeek.Sunday.GetHashCode()) % 7); // get first sunday.
}
```